# Python transpose a single row to column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I know this question has been asked in multiple threads in stackoverflow, but I haven't able to achieve how I wanted data to be transposed. I am complete beginner at python mostly work with sql.

I have values saved in dataframe in format like mentioned below

```
order_id  primary_dish  primary_cat  dish_id
912574      54465          2423        54481
912574      54465          2423        54540
912574      54481          2425        54465    
912574      54481          2425        54540    
912574      54540          2429        54481
912574      54540          2429        54465
```

I want this data to be represented as

```
order_id    primary_dish   primary_cat    54481  5450  54465  
912574      54465           2423              1    1     0
912574      54481           2425              0    1     1
912574      54540           2429              1    0     1
```

Basically the last column `dish_id` in the saved data frame df is
transposed and the values present for that primary dish are represented by 1 
and if not present are represented by 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [5]: df.pivot_table(index=['order_id','primary_dish','primary_cat'],
                       columns='dish_id', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0) \
          .reset_index()
Out[5]:
dish_id  order_id  primary_dish  primary_cat  54465  54481  54540
0          912574         54465         2423      0      1      1
1          912574         54481         2425      1      0      1
2          912574         54540         2429      1      1      0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot 
This is exactly how i wanted

Answer (score 1):

More easy way. using `pd.crosstab`

```
 pd.crosstab(df['dish_id'],[df['order_id'],df['primary_dish'],df['primary_cat']]).T.reset_index()
```